# How to split lines in Haskell?

Tags: variables, haskell, split, line

I have made a program which takes a 1000 digit number as input.
It is fixed, so I put this input into the code file itself.
I would obviously be storing it as Integer type, but how do I do it?

I have tried the program by having 1000 digits in the same line. I know this is the worst possible code format! But it works.

How can assign the variable this number, and split its lines. I read somewhere something about eos? Ruby, end of what?

I was thinking that something similar to comments could be used here.

Help will be appreciated.

the basic idea is to make this work:

```
a=3847981438917489137897491412341234
983745893289572395725258923745897232
```

instead of something like this:

```
a=3847981438917489137897491412341234983745893289572395725258923745897232
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Haskell doesn't have a way to split (non-`String`) literals across multiple lines. Since `String`s are an exception, we can shoehorn in other literals by parsing a multiline `String`:

```
v = read
    "32456\
    \23857\
    \23545" :: Integer
```

Alternately, you can use list syntax if you think it's prettier:

```
v = read . concat $
    ["32456"
    ,"24357"
    ,"23476"
    ] :: Integer
```

The price you pay for this is that some work will be done (once) at runtime, namely, the parsing (e.g. `read`).

Comment: Does ghc (probably) optimize this to a single string?

Comment: @MdxBhmt The first one _is_ a single `String` -- no optimization needed there. I don't think GHC currently does very much compile-time evaluation unless you explicitly request it (e.g. via Template Haskell), so my guess is the `concat` (in the second case) and the `read` (in both cases) are not optimized away at all.

Comment: @MdxBhmt (Indeed, a quick look at the output of `-ddump-simpl` confirms my suspicions.)